# PHP parse CSV by columns

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I would like to ask for help with this task: I have CSV for example like this:

```
column1$column2$column3
123$xyz$321
456$zyx$654
```

And I would like to parse it by PHP to Arrays by columns / headers -> for example

```
$column1 = {123,456}
$column2 = {xyz,zyx}
$column3 = {321,654}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Which version of PHP? This might be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: I have tried this:
`$columns = Array(Array());

$file = fopen($input, 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 0, "$")) !== FALSE) {
    //$line is an array of the csv elements
    $x = count($line);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
        if (count($columns) <= $i) {
            $columns[$i] = Array();
        }
        array_push($columns[$i], $line[$i]);
    }

    //print_r($line);
}

print_r($columns);

fclose($file);`

Comment: [edit] that into your question.  Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code and explanations:

```
$file = file("example.csv");              // read the file to an array
$cols = array();
for ($i=1;$i<count($file);$i++) {         // loop over $file, 
                                          // starting in the second line
    $row = explode('$', $file[$i]);       // make an array with explode
    for ($j=0;$j<count($row);$j++)        // loop over the $row array
        array_push($cols["column".$j], $row[$j]);
                                          // push it to the cols array
}
print_r($cols);
```

What are your curly brackets supposed to do? In PHP an array is formed with `[]`.
Rather than reading the whole file to an array you could as well read each line and push it to the cols array.